# nodejs exiting immediately without at error message

Tags: node.js

I've installed the latest Node.js for Windows x64 (0.8.19). When I run it, with or without a script file argument it just exits without an error message.

Things I've tried:

- I ran node.exe under JetBrains Webstorm, this reported an exit code of -1073740791

  I compiled the source code for 0.8.19 using VS2010, this has the same problem in release but in debug it reports the error: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'buf' was corrupted. Continuing from this in debug allows the program to start up.

  I installed node.js on my PC at home which is also Win 7 x64 and that worked fine.

Have others had the same problem?

Comment: two questions, how did you install (there's separate installer + binary), and did you try re-installing it? windows 7 also here, no such issues.

Comment: @eis, I used the .msi installer. I did try reinstalling it. My home PC works fine but I need it at work. Work PC has VS2010 installed and Sophos AntiVirus but otherwise mostly the same as home PC that works.

Comment: Hi, @Paul. did you manage to resolve the problem? I've got something similar.

Comment: @Yurly: No, sorry. I tried again a few weeks later with a different PC and that was OK.